# How to combine LIKE and IN in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find out if specific good is a commodity or a service.

I have two tables of importance, GoodsClass and PubVars.

GoodsClass has a hierarchy of goods which are defined by it's SortKey, eg. goods class with SortKey value of 01 is a parent to goods class with SortKey value of 0101 and all other goods classes that have their SortKey start with 01.

PubVars tells me which of these GoodsClass is a commodity class, and which is a service class.

I've tried this query, but the subquery returns more than one value so it cannot work like this:

```
SELECT GoodsClassId 
FROM GoodsClass 
WHERE SortKey LIKE (SELECT SortKey FROM GoodsClass 
                    WHERE GoodsClassId IN (SELECT VarId 
                                           FROM PubVars 
                                           WHERE VarName IN ('Commodity', 'Service'))) + '%'
```

How can I rewrite this query so that I can retrieve the GoodsClassId's I need?

I don't really know how to give nice sample data, but let's put it like this...
PubVars has IDs of 216 for 'Commodity', and 203 for 'Service'.

[image]
[image]

So, I need my query to return all IDs on both of the pictures (IDs 203-212 and 216-221).

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @Janko What exactly are trying to achieve?.. Get the all the GoodsClass with the specified `VarName`?...or... All top GoodsClass which has at least one child (or itself) with the specified `VarName` in the hierarchy?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've provided sample data and desired results.

Comment: @Luis I've added additional info, please tell me if I need to provide additional info.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your current logic using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT gc.GoodsClassId
FROM GoodsClass gc
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT gc2.SortKey
              FROM GoodsClass gc2
              WHERE gc2.GoodsClassId IN (SELECT pv.VarId
                                         FROM PubVars pv
                                         WHERE pv.VarName IN ('Commodity', 'Service')
                                        ) AND
                    gc.SortKey LIKE gc2.SortKey + '%'
             );
```

That said, I think there are probably better ways to write this logic.  But without sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic, it is hard to make suggestions.  You can ask a *new* question, if you want to investigate that.

Comment: When trying to run this query, I get: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXISTS'.

Comment: @Janko remove the "SortKey LIKE" from the query

Comment: @AntonínLejsek I did as you suggested, but I don't get desired results.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek My bad, actually, it works great :) Thanks :)